# Can't start spotify snap

Tags: snap, gtk, spotify

I have the problem that my spotify doesn usually not start. When I do `spotify` in the terminal, I get the following errors:

```
Gtk-Message: 17:35:09.563: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 17:35:09.563: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: 17:35:09.568: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

I already tried reinstalling spotify with

```
snap remove --purge spotify
snap install spotify
```

and fixing the errors by running

```
sudo apt-get install libatk-adaptor libgail-common
```

In fact, I worked my way through the first two pages of google results, but no dice. I did not do anything to my system in that regard, so that error does not come from me changing stuff I were not supposed to. I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS 64-bit with the most up-to-date software.

Any idea on what it could be?

Also, sometimes (like one in ten or twenty times), I do still get those errors, but spotify starts just fine.

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04, and unsuccessfully tried the same fixes as you (probably). Interestingly, my Spotify always starts as expected (unlike your 5-10% success chance) ... I am just confused about the error messages. And it seems to be the case for several versions of Ubuntu.